# Synchronization List <String> with file on HDD

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, binding, synchronization

What is the best way for BindingList synchronization with File on HDD or network drive ?

For example :

I have file Employers.txt on my hard drive, I can successfully read it and populate my List. 
Each file row will be the new List item.

If someone will edit my file on hard drive, is there any possibility to note me about it so I can re-read it and re-populate my List object.
It would be nice if I could know which information was added to the list, so I wouldn't need to re-read all file and could add only modified or newly added information.

Of course, I could make it by the timer but if the file is quite big, it's not good approuch.

The question is :

**How can I stay file and List synchronized with each other ?**

Comment: Google for `FileSystemWatcher`. You will still have to re-read the whole file though.

Comment: Thank you for help, it's certainly a right answer on my question, could you clarify one more thing for me. 

 I have a little doubt ,should I use it for detecting changes in the file if I am going to use Microsoft Sync Framework  ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Microsoft Sync Framework. Looks like there's a good amount of documentation online though. If you can't figure it out, I'd ask a new question tagged with `microsoft-sync-framework`.

Comment: yeah, I know I was asking you just for the case you know it already. 
Anyway, thank you for your help.